# How to do antilog(x) calculation in ubuntu calculator?

Tags: gnome-calculator

Using 20.04 default calculator in advanced mode:  I am needing to do multiple complex calculations that require antilog - how do I do it? Every syntax I have tried fails. What buttons do I press, in what order? Need to do this work - do not want to have to dig out ancient log/antilog paper tables and manually input those numbers!

Comment: `log_b^-1(x) = b^x`?

Comment: `10 ^ x` or `e ^ x` depending on the logarithm _base_.